# Running iex mix phoenix.server on a different port does not work

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This looks like a bug but I am not sure. 
Can anyone tell if running iex on different port number works. It always uses port 4000.

```
PORT=4001 iex -S mix phoenix.server   

Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

[info] Running AppMessenger.Endpoint with Cowboy using http on port 4000
Interactive Elixir (1.2.5) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> 19 May 19:53:40 - info: compiled 5 files into 2 files, copied 3 in 714ms
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `config/dev.exs` has a hardcoded value `4000` for the port in Phoenix. If you want to use the value from `PORT` environment variable in `dev`, in `config/dev.exs` change:

```
http: [port: 4000]
```

to

```
http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}]
```

Comment: But now have have to add: export PORT=4000 as default.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to specify a fallback with the `{:system, "PORT"}` method: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/47064424f9d65ad66d74120e7c5e1b365d8d7cc6/lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex#L31-L34.

Comment: A fallback would be nice. Meanwhile, this works better that the default for development for me.